# Need help using a nested join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join an `ID#` field from `tableA` to the `ID#` field in `tableB` so I can join the `NAME` field in `tableB` to the `NAME` field in `tableC`. Currently using CTE's and I would like to accomplish this without the need of a CTE.

Currently doing:

```
WITH t 
AS 
(
    SELECT  tableB.ID# 
    FROM    tableA
    INNER JOIN tableB ON (tableA.ID_REF#  = tableB.ID_REF#)
),
u as 
( 
    SELECT  NAME 
    FROM    tableC
)     
SELECT  u.NAME 
FROM    t 
INNER JOIN u ON (t.ID# = u.ID#)
```

I'm assuming I'm able to do the same thing with a nested join?

Answer (score 0):

> join an ID # field from tableA to the ID # field in tableB so I can join the NAME field in table B to the NAME field in tableC.

Why use CTEs?  Just chain the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT . . .   -- whatever you want here
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b  
     ON a.ID_REF# = b.ID_REF# JOIN
     tableC c
     ON b.Name = c.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you don't need a CTE - you can join twice. Based on your problem statement, that would be:

```
select c.name
from tableC c
inner join tableB b on b.name = c.name
inner join tableA a on a.id# = b.id#
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join outputs the same result no matter the order of join ( a -> b -> c, c -> b -> a). Also note that default join without any keyword will be `inner join`.

So you can do like this (c->a->b):

```
select ...
from tableC c
join tableB b on b.name = c.name
join tableA a on a.ID_REF# = b.ID_REF#
```

or this (a->b->c):

```
select ...
from tableA a
join tableB b on a.ID_REF# = b.ID_REF#
join tableC c on b.name = c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @TableA table (ID int ,Name nvarchar(50))
Declare @TableB table(ID int, Name nvarchar(50))
Declare @TableC table (ID int , Name nvarchar(50))

insert into @TableA values(1,'Chit'),(2,'Mar'),(3,'Thiri')
insert into @TableB values(1,'Chit'),(2,'Mar'),(3,'Thiri')
insert into @TableC values(1,'Chit'),(2,'Mar'),(3,'Thiri')


select c.ID,c.Name from @TableC c inner join (select b.Name from @TableA a inner join @TableB b on a.ID =b.ID  Group by b.Name) bb on bb.Name=c.Name
```